# create a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How do I create a batch script that can copy data from ten different text files into one text file, for example:

```
 test1.txt
 test2.txt
 test3.txt
 test4.txt
```

Copy data to one text file:

```
 final.txt = test1.txt
             test2.txt
             test3.txt
             test4.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a batch file, the `copy` command can do it all by itself:

```
copy test1.txt + text2.txt + ... +testN.txt final.txt
```

Or:

```
copy "test*.txt" final.txt
```

Comment: thank but my question is i want to copy inside data of this text file

Answer (score 0):

Just use the type command

```
type test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt text4.txt > final.txt
```

File contents will be written to the final.txt file, while the names of the files are written to stderr (so still appear in command prompt window). If you don't want the stderr output then

```
( type test1.txt & type test2.txt & type test3.txt & type text4.txt ) > final.txt
```

Either way, the contents of final.txt is the concatentation of all the input files.

Comment: If you don't want the stderr output you can simply append `2>nul` at the end of the first command line ...

Comment: thank but my question is i want to copy inside data of this text file

Comment: Sorry, did I misunderstand the question.Both my solutiuon, and the one from @Mat will leave teh contents of final.txt to be the concatenation of the contents of the files test1.txt ... testN.txt. Just various windows ways of doing the unix command `cat test1.txt test2.txt ... testN.txt > final.txt`